# "PushPlugin not found" using Cordova 2.5 for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PushPlugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and Cordova 2.5 for an iOS applicaiton.

In my Plugins folder I have these files:

- Appdelegate+notification.h
- Appdelegate+notification.m
- PushPlugin.h
- PushPlugin.m

In config.xml I have included the plugin like this:
`<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="PushPlugin" />`

I have also PushNotification.js in my www folder and included that in index.html.

When I run the application and execute the line in my push.js file:

`pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":app.onNotificationAPN"});`

Then I get this error:

`Error: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml`

Is PushPlugin compatible with Cordova 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue when trying to get the pushplugin to work.  I got it working by putting this block of code inside the config.xml (not the one in the www folder, but the one in the project folder)

```
<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="PushPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/ios/AppDelegate+notification.m" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/PushPlugin.m" />

    <header-file src="src/ios/AppDelegate+notification.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/PushPlugin.h" />

</platform>
```

If you download the sample project from git, there's a file called plugin.xml that has a bunch of stuff that needs to be added to the xml (I think).

Hope that helps.